# Spring Native 0.9.1-SNAPSHOT fails to start in IDEA

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, native, spring-native

Just generated on https://start.spring.io/ Spring Boot 2.4.4 project with added Spring Boot Native 0.9.1-SNAPSHOT

and it fails to start within IDEA (so not yet even as native image)

> The ApplicationContext could not start as 'org.springframework.aot.StaticSpringFactories' that is generated by the Spring AOT plugin could not be found.

Full output

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=52158:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath ....
2021-03-20 22:07:21.264 ERROR 10192 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The ApplicationContext could not start as 'org.springframework.aot.StaticSpringFactories' that is generated by the Spring AOT plugin could not be found.

Action:

Review your local configuration and make sure that the Spring AOT plugin is configured properly.
If you're trying to run your application with 'mvn spring-boot:run', please use 'mvn package spring-boot:run' instead.
See https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-aot for more details.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I noticed that for my usual project with Web and JPA over hibernate some extra maven plugin were added by Initializr:

```xml
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny</builder>
                        <env>
                            <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>true</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>
                        </env>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-native.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enhance</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                            <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
                            <enableDirtyTracking>true</enableDirtyTracking>
                            <enableAssociationManagement>true</enableAssociationManagement>
                            <enableExtendedEnhancement>false</enableExtendedEnhancement>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Checking https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-aot `Sources are generated in target/generated-sources/spring-aot/`

So I did run maven from command line `mvn package` and could move to next error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do read https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-aot carefully, it has exact steps for IDEA (and tips for Eclipse and VSCode)

> In the Maven tool window, go to "Plugins" and map:
>
> - Right click on `spring-aot:generate` then click on "After build".
> - Add the JUnit configuration (or just try to run a firs time your tests) and then right click on `spring-aot:test-generate then click on "Execute Run/Debug …​" then select your JUnit test configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snapshot to config it in my IDE.

[image]